# Why is canceling a key-down not working if I display an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to cancel a key down, which works when I do not display an alert.

If I display one, it does not work.

JS Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/phbmvg8y/1/

Why is that?

```
<body>
  Without alert it works - with alert it does not
  <input type="text" class="noalert" value="without alert">
  <input type="text" class="alert" value="with alert">
  <div class="alert" contenteditable=true>alert</div>
  <div class="noalert" contenteditable=true>noalert</div>
</body>
```

---

```
$('.alert').on('keydown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  window.alert('keydown intercepted');
  return false;
});

$('.noalert').on('keydown', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3):

It is because of how `keydown` works. [From jQuery docs:](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

> The keydown event is sent to an element when the user first presses a
>   key on the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event
>   is only sent to the element that has the focus

When you display the `alert`, the element loses the focus, and the focus is transferred to the alert box. That is why you get a differential behaviour for the two cases you mentioned.

Comment: This does not appear to be relevant to me: the quote here deals with which element the event is *sent* to, not why a handler would fail to `preventDefault` after the event was sent. The browser's decision of where to send the event is made strictly prior to the execution of the handler function.

Comment: @apsillers, I can see your concern but I am sure that `preventDefault` has nothing to do in this case. You can try removing it. I will update the answer in some time.

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with the order that the user's action is trapped and the event is raised. To do what you require use `keypress` instead:

```
$('.alert').on('keypress', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.alert('keypress intercepted');
    return false;
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/phbmvg8y/4/)

Comment: It's due to the inconsistencies in the way the key bound events work. See [this article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/keyboard_events_in_javascript.htm) for more info